# How to change "archive folder" in Outlook 365 / android app to make them match?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

On my desktop using Outlook 365 desktop app the folder that is used to archive mail is called "Archief". But when I archive something on my Android phone it will be moved to "Archive". How can I make them use the same folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, that should be related to the account type you configured to your Outlook. So, what's the type of your account on your desktop Outlook 365 and on your Android app? POP, IMAP or Exchange? According to my tests, if you are using Office 365 Exchange email account on both devices, they can match and sync automatically.

Comment: It's the same 365 work email

Comment: Have you configured your O365 email account as Exchange account on both devices?

Comment: Ye,s I did :) (padding for min length)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your issue before? If you mean that their folder name not match instead of its folder content, you could try /resetfoldernames command-line to see if your issue could be resolved. (Press Win + R, type “outlook /resetfoldernames”, press Enter.)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#ID0EAABAAA=Outlook

Comment: How is everything going now? Have you got your issue fixed yet?

Comment: thank you for asking, still didn't find the time to switch the interface language but yes it seems this is the solution.

Comment: Good news! Remember to try it and see if it could resolve your issue. If it could indeed work fine, it would be so nice of you to accept my reply as the answer.

Comment: Of course I will!

Comment: Any update yet?

Comment: Yes it now works, thank you :)